Conda Environment Rename Causing Jupyter Launch Error
My OS system is windows 11.
I recently attempted to rename a Conda environment from ML to ML2 using a command
conda rename -n ML ML2

After renaming, I tried to activate the new environment and run Jupyter Notebook:
jupyter notebook

However, I encountered the following error:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
'"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ML\python.exe"
"C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\ML2\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook':
???????????

It seems that Jupyter is still looking for the Python executable in the old environment path. I've checked that the ML2 environment is activated correctly, but the issue persists.
Could anyone offer guidance on how to correctly update the internal paths of a renamed Conda environment, or provide a workaround for this issue?

Please report the exact command you used to launch Jupyter. I suspect this problem is caused by whatever paths or env variables you have in your OS env (bashrc or what not).

Still not enough information. Did you first activate the new conda environment? Do you have any jupyter specific global env variables defined (such as JUPYTER_PLATFORM_DIRS or JUPYTER_PREFER_ENV_PATH)(you can normally inspect those with jupyter --paths --debug)?

@mudskipper  I first activate the new conda environment. When I run jupyter --paths --debug after activating the new conda environment. It gives the similar error  Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ML\python.exe" "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\ML2\Scripts\jupyter.exe" --paths --debug: ???????

Ok - I don't know what's going on your system, but I suspect you have some other global env setting (not related to Jupyter) that still refers to the old location where jupyter used to be. Jupyter itself will (afaik) not store that by default - definitely not if you only renamed a conda env (I tested) and you didn't set up a special config. But you could also empty out your Jupyter cache dir and see if that works.

I would in your case, just uninstall jupyter (and also remove the jupyter cache dir) and reinstall.
